# Extent to xy coordinate- arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, extents, valueerror

I work with arcview 10.3, and i try to extent to xy coordinate with arcpy?

I am using this code:

```
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
pnt = '178434 ,662446'
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0] 
    df.extent = pnt
    print 'extent'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

but i get en error:

> ValueError: Invalid string value for Extent argument

Answer (score 4):

you need (at least) 4 values to define an extent. And you should provide those values in a list of numbers or using the properties of the [extent object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000006r000000) (e.g. XMin), not in a string. For example

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
newExtent = df.extent
newExtent.XMin, newExtent.YMin = -180.0, -90.0
newExtent.XMax, newExtent.YMax = 180.0, 90.0
df.extent = newExtent
```

EDIT: in order to zoom "to a point", you still need to set an extent window (a point has no dimension). For example (zoom on a square of 200*200 centered on your point)

```
pointX, pointY = 178434, 662446
size = 100
newExtent.XMin, newExtent.XMax = pointX - size, pointX + size
newExtent.YMin, newExtent.YMax = pointY - size, pointY + size
```

Comment: but i want to zoom to specific xy coordinate,how can i do it? maybe it wrong to use extent operation?

Comment: well, then you can compute the corners of your extent based on  your central value. See my edit